# How to work with not (yet) registered devise Users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a User model, for login and registration, its email field is used (everything vanilla from the devise gem).

I want (other) users to be able to e.g. add Users to a team, with the email-address as the identifier.

That is fine when the User is already existing (pseudo `@team.users.add(User.find_by(email: other_users_email))`) but I am unsure how to handle situations where the **user does not yet exist** (did not [yet] register).
When a (new) User sets up a new account, for the example above after successfull registration `current_user.teams` should show up correctly.

I do not want to force these potentially new users to use the system (e.g. using devise_invitable) and bother them with an email.

I followed the path of creating the User when a user with the given email does not yet exist, but then when the user actually tries to setup an account, it fails (email not unique).

Alternatively, I could remodel the TeamMember-part and let it optionally either store an email-adress or the reference to an existing User. Then what I would need is to check for "open" TeamMembers directly after User-Account-creation (so, TeamMembers with the given email). I could also do this on each requst, but that looks too expensive to me. There might be race conditions, but I could live with that (and check for the every-now-in-a-millenia-gap with a cron-job).

Any pointers? I am sure this is not that unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

When a user A adds user B to a team by email, create the object for that user B, but set a flag, something like `auto_created_and_inactive: true`

When user B signs up on the site, you just have to handle this in your `users#create`: first, try to find an auto-created record and update it (set a password or whatever; also reset the flag). Or otherwise proceed with the usual route of creating a new record.

Comment: Well, I use the default devise-controller (just edited my question to reflect that not only in the heading but also in the first sentence), if everything fails I could indeed re-open that one, but hoping for a nicer path. Thanks Sergio.

Comment: @Felix: see, that's why devise is so customizable. So that you can do things like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I did not yet tried @sergio-tulentsevs approach (implement RegistrationController#create). But to complete what I sketched in my question:

`User` model can define an `after_confirmation` method, which is called after ... confirmation! So, if I store every information about a potential user with a reference to his/her email-adress, once he/she registered I can query this information and e.g. complete Team-Memberships.

```
# app/models/user.rb
def after_confirmation
  # (pseudo-code, did not try)
  self.teams < TeamMembership.open.where(email: self.email)
end
```